# iOS 7 navigation bar of uinvigationcontroller issue

Tags: ios, ios7

I have attached how UI looks on the different iOS versions.

This is my code below:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contactsViewController];
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

iOS 6

[image]

iOS 7

[image]

First problem is status bar in iOS 6 I have not status bar. Second problem is overdrawing two views. How to solve it?

Comment: The new iOS7 navigation bar is part of the status bar, what's happening is your navigation bar background image isn't big enough, so it is being repeated again to fill the total height.

Comment: Please refer apple doc(https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW1) about new bar changes. You will able to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the status bar in the presented viewcontroller by writing this method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to use a **resizable** image:

```
[image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Or, as **AliSoftware** suggested, set the extended layout edges to `UIRectEdgeNone` (be sure to check if `edgesForExtendedLayout` is supported (your app will crash if it ties to assign this property running on iOS 6.x device):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for this answer, can you see on my comment to the alisoftware, this condition really works but there are no changes with appearance. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly invite you to read Apple's "UI Transition Guide" which explains all these differences between iOS6 and iOS7 and how to adapt your code accordingly.

The easiest way if you want your view to still be under your statusBar even in iOS7 is to set your `UIViewController`'s `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` in its `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I present ABPeoplePickerNavigationController so I have not permission to viewDidLoad, of course I can inherit from this class and overwrite viewDidLoad, but the problem that I have added this code self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone to the each my view controllers but it still does not work. I want to draw your that the problem is not with ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, the problem with all controllers that I have. Maybe I need some additional setup for example for status bar etc. Thanks